# Migrating system to another VPS

Tags: server, mysql, php, nginx

I am new to Ubuntu. Is there any management software that would save some sort of system image that I may copy to a new VPS if needed?

I have a DigitalOcean droplet with Ubuntu, `nginx`, `php-fpm`, `redis MySQL`. I followed some tutorials when I first set up each service. If I were to move to another VPS, even if I would go through the initial setup again, is there any way I can save the settings I made to Ubuntu, `nginx` etc. So that next time I need to migrate everything would be easier?

I found some migrating tutorials but I was looking for some sort of automatic solution.

Comment: This seems like one classic reason for backups: So you can restore onto a new system.

Comment: I concur with user5357333; backups are the way to go if you're looking for a one-off solution. A more modern approach would be to set up Docker containers and simply use the setup script to pull the base image from Docker and source code from a Git repository somewhere, but that's probably overkill for your needs.